# Is there a way to remove the border of the legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, statistics, plot, ggplot2

I'm using qplot to plot a function and I want to position the legend within the plot. I've used

```
opts( legend.position = c(0.7,0.7) )
```

to move the legend where I want it to be.

However there is a white border around the legend and that shows up on the gray background.

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
x = c(1:20)
y = c(1:20)

p <- qplot(x,y, color = "blue")

p <- p + scale_colour_identity("Example", breaks=c("blue"), labels=c("dots"))

p <- p + opts(legend.position = c(0.6, 0.4))

print(p)
```

I would like to know how to remove this border from the legend. Thank you.

Comment: You only need to use c() around multiple values so 1:20, "blue" and "dots" dont need the use of c() combine function. Thought I'd mention in case that saves some typing or helps otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For newer version of `ggplot`, `opts` is replaced by `theme` & `theme_rect` is replaced by `element_rect`

```
p + theme(legend.background = element_rect(color = NA))
```

---

This will get rid of your border:

```
p + opts(legend.background = theme_rect(col = 0))
```

other options in addition to col (which applies to the border) are fill (background) and size (which is the border size).

Hope that helps!

All the best,

Jay

Comment: Thanks Jay - that worked perfectly. When you mentioned fill(background) is that used similarly? e.g. opts(legend.fill = "white")? I tried combinations of this without success.

Comment: p + opts(legend.background = theme_rect(col = "red", size = 2, fill = "blue"))

Comment: This will give you a slightly thicker red border and a blue backgound. Does that help? Let me know if that works

Comment: Yes that does help, thank you. Now I understand how to use it.